# Will clear call reset on shared smart pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reset, smart-pointers, stdvector

I have recently changed my raw pointer to use `std::shared_ptr` within a container like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractPathContainer>> mGeneratedPaths;
```

When i call `clear()` on this container, will it call `reset()` method on each `std::shared_ptr` within it?

Comment: Genetic containers treat all type the same way: is there a call to `.reset()` in `vector<int>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will call the destructors. Destructors will decrease reference count for each smart pointer, if it brings to `0`  then destructor calls to free function (by default this is delete wrapper). So if you did something like:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractPathContainer>> mGeneratedPaths ({c1, std::shared_ptr<AbstractPathContainer>(new AbstractPathContainerImpl())  });
std::shared_ptr<AbstractPathContainer> smartRef = mGeneratedPaths[0];
 mGeneratedPaths.clear();
```

`smartRef` will not be removed from heap.

Answer (score 6):

No; it will call the destructor on each pointer   (which may or may not call `reset()`).

If your question is really "will my memory be freed if appropriate?" then the answer is yes; the ref count will be adjusted as required for each shared ptr object, and if it's 0 then the object will be deleted.

Comment: `(which may or may not call reset())`.,due to the.... ref count worth adding that in maybe?

Comment: @SamerTufail and the implementation ... it may decide to do it inline in the destructor because ... it can;   but sure, I'll update the answer :)

Comment: It wasn't critisicm really, more of a would it help the OP or anyone else understand better. (: